# Lean indexer for address transactions

Tags: transactions, monitoring

I am on the lookout for a lean service that can discover and return all transactions for an address. The discovery should be for past blocks aswell as future ones.

With *lean* I mean something akin to a headless systemd service that serves raw and/or json transaction data per query.

Any pointers on recipes on how to strip down existing frills-rich tools to base service is welcome, too.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to query here. Can you give an example? If you have an address `A` what do you want to query on this address?

Comment: all transactions for that address, for example.

Comment: Going to or from that address? If you want all transactions to that address then you will need an archive node.

Comment: That's fine. But if I run say a `geth` node myself, is there a query I can do directly against that node that gets me "all the txs for a particular address?" There didn't use to be last time I used it, I think... that's what I'm after - a service that proxies the node and generated/indexes data I have an interest in. How should I rephrase the question to make this more clear?